# Undefined reference on roscpp functions

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm stuck with a linking problem for a while now, I tried many stuff and browsed the forum but couldn't find my exact problem. It must be quite stupid though, since it seems to be a simple fail in linking roscpp.

When I tried to catkin_make my workspace, I get an undefined reference to any function from roscpp. It does not seem to be an inclusion problem since I have no error message about that, only this undefined reference issue.

I simplified my .cpp and my CMakelist.txt to the maximum but still get the same problem. Here are the exact files I'm trying :

CMakelist.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(myproject)

if(UNIX)
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
endif()


find_package(
  catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  )

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )


catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES myproject
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy
  DEPENDS system_lib
  )

add_executable(lj_cmd_interface src/lj_cmd_interface.cpp)


target_link_libraries(lj_cmd_interface ${CATKIN_LIBRARIES})
```

package.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>myproject</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description></description>

  <maintainer email="me@me.com">Me</maintainer>

  <license>BSD</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>

</package>
```

And even the simplest cpp code doesn't work :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  ros::init(argc, argv, "mynode");
  
  return 0;
}
```

I guess the solution must be quite straightforward once you get it, but after almost a whole day searching for it I must admit I couldn't see it...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210407/undefined-reference-on-roscpp-functions/) by [francoisdtf](https://answers.ros.org/users/19816/francoisdtf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> target_link_libraries(lj_cmd_interface ${CATKIN_LIBRARIES})
> ```

If that is an actualy copy/paste, then you should change `CATKIN_LIBRARIES` to `catkin_LIBRARIES` (note the case change).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [francoisdtf](https://answers.ros.org/users/19816/francoisdtf/) on 2015-06-02**:
That was an actual copy paste. Thank you and sorry for the trouble, that was the issue.